# How to implement buffer to fetch an array of string and parse it? (ATmega16 in C eclipse)

Tags: buffer, uart, isr

i want to fetch an array of string like this:
`#s;12;34;56:`
i put the data into buffer so the data can be parsed/processed. so the data must contain a '#' in the first buffer index and a ':' in the last buffer index to be processed.
if that symbol found, send some respond to terminal, like respond 'k'.
when i tested the code in realterm, the result still had some error.
i get confused where to put the BufferWrite() function when i use ISR.
here's my code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 8
#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)
/*#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)*/

volatile char datas[BUFF_SIZE]; 
volatile int index;
volatile int i;
volatile uint8_t flag_uart = 0;
void USART0Init(void)
{
    // set berhasil
    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) | (1 << RXCIE);
    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0);

    UBRRH = (uint8_t) (UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
    UBRRL = (uint8_t) UBRR_VALUE;
    // Set frame format to 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
    //UCSRC |= (1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0);
    //enable reception and RC complete interrupt

}

void indexing ()
{
    index = 0;
    i = 0;
}
int BufferWrite()
{
    //datas[i] = UDR;
    if (i < BUFF_SIZE) 
{
    //datas[i] = UDR;
    i = index++;
    datas[i]; // increment

    return 0;
}
else
{
    if((datas[0] == '#') || (datas[7] == ':')){
    UDR = datas[i];
    //UDR = ('k');
    i = 0; //reset
    return 0;
    //}

}


return 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    USART0Init();
    indexing();
    //BufferWrite();
    sei(); // Enable the Global Interrupt Enable flag so that interrupts can be processed
    //BufferInit(&buf);

    for (;;) // Loop forever
    {
        if (flag_uart == 1) {
        flag_uart = 0;
        datas[i] = UDR; //a itu receive
        BufferWrite();
    }
}
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect){

//BufferWrite();
flag_uart = 1;
   //datas[i] = UDR;
   // Fetch the received byte value into the variable "data". u
   // UDR = datas[i];
   //UDR = data; // Echo back the received byte back to the computer

}
```